# Asp.Net, accessing variables from previous page a good approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net

While redirecting from page to page generally i used to pass values as querystring but as you know query string is not a good approach as there are many security concerns and more over its having a maximum size is of 256 Bytes or ie length 2048 characters. So is it a good approach to access variables by setting previous page ie `"<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="" %>"` and accessing previous page items

Please let me know, is there any other way for passing variables other than `Sessions` and is using Previous page concept a Good Approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here is from MSDN's [How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx):

> You can pass information between pages in various ways, some of which
>   depend on how the redirection occurs. The following options are
>   available even if the source page is in a different ASP.NET Web
>   application from the target page, or if the source page is not an
>   ASP.NET Web page:
>
> - Use a query string.
> - Get HTTP POST information from the source page.
>
> The following options are available only when the source and target
>   pages are in the same ASP.NET Web application.
>
> - Use session state.
> - Create public properties in the source page and access the property      values in the target page.
> - Get control information in the target page from controls in the       source page.

So assuming you have the same ASP.NET application PreviousPage property is what exactly was designed for your case.

Answer (score 0):

`PreviousPage` is intended for use with cross-page postbacks. If that's what you're doing, then there's nothing wrong with it.

Without a postback, a reference to an instance of the previous page class won't (shouldn't) contain any state information.

If you're just using a link from one page to another, it's better to use something like session state, cookies, or your database. If you're doing a redirect, there are a few more options (including the use of `Server.Transfer()` instead of doing an actual redirect).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a alternative approach, you should keep you data in **context.items**

This approach is very useful to save data in between two or more sequential pages. Its a simple approach used same as:

```
Context.Items.Add("SOMETHING","somevalue");
```

*** You need to use ***Server.Transfer***

instead of Response.Redirect. Because if you use Response.Redirect method, your context would be cleared and you cannot get any values.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Server.Transfer is a serious limitation. Even doing that, why you will ever need to use non-typed collection instead of typed PreviousPage property?

Comment: Yes exactly, but Its also light weighted approach then Response.Redirect. As he is asking a good approach for passing data between Two pages... I guess it would be appropriate.

Comment: Light weighted in term of what? In terms of maintainability it's heavy weighted. And this is significant.